# how to check if the result of a bash function is a specific string in while loop?

Tags: bash

(I'm not a linux guy) and I want to check the status of a service when its updating (takes about 10 minutes) to make sure it is successful. I use a function to run the status command and while loop as follow:

```
get_status() { echo ...my command runs here and return the statue; }
```

I simply can get the status like `$(get_status)`. Now I want to see what is the status and take action:

```
while $(get_status) == "PENDING"; do echo retrying... && sleep 5; done
```

I've tried different ways like single/double brackets but cannot get the while comparison to work properly? Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1):

The `while` loop doesn't know anything about comparison tests. It only knows how to check the exit status of a command, and `$(get_status) == "PENDING"` is not a command. The brackets you want are for either a `test` command or a `bash` conditional expression command.

```
while test "$(get_status)" = "PENDING"; do
```

or

```
# [ is a synonym for test, with the added requirement that
# there be a final argument ] to complete the illusion of
# syntax.
while [ "$(get_status) = "PENDING" ]; do
```

or

```
while [[ $(get_status) == "PENDING" ]]; do
```

In the first two cases, `=` is preferred as the correct equality operator for `test`/`[`. In the last case, `==` may be used, and the quotes can be dropped around `$(get_status)` because no word-splitting or filename generation is performed on expansions in `[[ ... ]]`. (The quotes *could* be dropped around the literal word `PENDING` in all three cases, but could remain necessary for some right-hand arguments inside `[[ ... ]]` for reasons beyond the scope of this question.)

Comment: Thanks @chepner.  Still not working! If I run `while [ "PENDING" = "PENDING" ]; do echo retrying && sleep 5; done` it works. If I run `while [ "$(get_status)" = "PENDING" ]; do echo retrying && sleep 5; done` not working however the `$(get_status)` returns `PENDING` in the terminal.

Comment: It seems it doesn't run my function at all.

Comment: `get_status` may be returning something like `PENDING\r`; how *exactly* is it defined?

Comment: it basically running an aws command `get_status() { echo aws mwaa get-environment --name <env-name> --query Environment.Status; }`.

Comment: Yeah, `get_status` outputs a string terminated with a CR/LF pair, and the command substitution only strips the trailing LF, leaving you with an unwanted CR in your value.